# no puedo instalar yum install composer en un contendor docker

Tags: linux, docker, centos

Tengo un proyecto en php con `docker`, estoy usando centos para instalar paquetes dentro del proyecto.

Además, estoy conectado en una maquina virtual de windows y dentro de la máquina virtual está el proyecto de docker.

Al momento de instalar composer me arroja el siguiente error:

```bash
[root@5aafa6f40f27 html]# yum install composer -y && composer install && composer update

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/? 
release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=container error was
14: HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden


One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
packages for the previous distribution release still work).

3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
    
    yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

    yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
or
    subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
compromise:

    yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true
```

Comment: es la version 7, se que esta deprecada, pero esta funcionando en nuestros proyectos

Comment: ¿Qué te resulta al actualizar con `yum upgrade`?

Comment: La misma respuesta

Comment: Agrega a tu pregunta el contenido de `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo`; Prueba después de comentar con `#` las líneas que comienzan con `mirrorlist=`. ¿De cuál repo quieres instalar Composer? Añádelo a la pregunta.